# Why won't Jenkins iterate with variables

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a script X times. It works when evaluating against a number but not against a variable. The second does **~40 iterations** and then succeeds. I am not a groovy guy but this worked in a groovy sandbox.

I ended up doing this w/o any groovy in a bash script but still would like to understand what happened.

```
   stages {
      stage('Testing') {
         steps {
           script {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         println "This is run " + i 
         }
         }
      }
   }
```

Below does not work - "count" is a variable.

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   environment {
       def count = 2
   }

   stages {
      stage('Testing') {
         steps {
           script {
                for (int i = 0; i < env.count; i++) {
                    println env.count
                    println "This is run " + i
                 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node (hide)
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/iterator-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Testing)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo
This is run 0
[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo
This is run 1
[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo
This is run 2
[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo
This is run 3
[Pipeline] echo
2
[Pipeline] echo (hide)
2
[Pipeline] echo
This is run 49
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is scoped within `environment` - stages can't see it. (You can verify this by printing value of count before you enter loop).

You can have it at the top of your Jenkisfile `count = 2` or to be neat if you have multiple variables you can have it in a class:

```
Class environment {
    static int count = 2
}
```

and access it via `environment.count`.

Comment: This is in Jenkins - things defined in environment _should_ be accessible anywhere and if I println "env.count" it gives me the correct value.

Comment: Ok, but I don’t see you calling it as env.count in your sample

Comment: I tried env.count & ${env.count} and ${count}. None of them seem to make it work. The thing that's weird is that it's evaluating wrong... 49 is definitely larger than 2 so what gives?

Comment: When you print out count can you use env.count

Comment: Tried it, identical result, updated question not to confuse people.

Comment: In theory if you do my suggestion of a separate class for variables, does it work?  I don't have any further ideas of why your version is not stopping when its a variable, but my gut says it not being static has to do with it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205966/discussion-between-thefiddlerwins-and-ceeplusplus).